# Should the onTouchListener call the same method multiple times when Tapped?

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener, ontouch

This is my first game app. I've built a card game, players can tap or drag a card. I've noticed that when a player taps a card, it appears tha the onTouch method fires multiple times. My basic code is as such:

```
cardView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

   Log.d(TAG, "Card is Touched");

   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         moveCardMethod();
   }

}
```

The method:

```
private void moveCardMethod() {

     Log.d(TAG, "Card Move method has started.");

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           Log.d(TAG, "Action down has started.");
           break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
           Log.d(TAG, "Action move has started.");
           break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           Log.d(TAG, "Action up has started.");
           break;

      Log.d(TAG, "The end.");
}
```

Results:

- Card is Touched
- Card Move method has started.
- Action down has started.
- Card is Touched
- Card Move method has started.
- Action move has started.
- Card is Touched
- Card Move method has started.
- Action up has started.
- The end.

Am I doing something incorrect? I would assume that when the card is tapped (or dragged), it would results in something like this:

- Card is Touched
- Card Move method has started.
- Action down has started.
- Action move has started.
- Action up has started.
- The end.

The code appears to work during the game, but this concerns me. From the log, it appears with a tap or drag "moveCardMethod()" is called multiple times.

I didn't want to move over complicate the example, but I have tried to use a isCardBusy boolean to ignore the method if isCardBusy = true. However, it really didn't work. Plus, it causes problems during the action move portion.

Since this is my first app, I am not confident I have implemented the onTouch correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yep you implemented it incorrectly, you should return true/false in the onTouch(..) function + add the drag code when the event.getAction() is ACTION_DOWN.

```
cardView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                    view);
            view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```